# unable to use the vs code server following their posted documentation but I am getting an error related to the syntax

Tags: visual-studio-code-server, vscode-server

the documentation I followed is here https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2022/07/07/vscode-server

running the "code-server" command throws these errors in relation to the syntax in the HTML.

[image]

I tried to add quotes around it as I saw in an article related to the issue but not this specific use case.